# Visual Studio Build Configuration - Release Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, build

In Visual Studio 2013 I see there is new configuration for build (Release Pro).

When deploying in production, I normally choose Release. So not sure what this Release Pro and how it differs from Release

[image]

Will it increase speed?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have no such new default configuration. Probably one or more of your projects have a custom configuration called RELEASE PRO with some kind of personalization (Conditionals symbols like #if DEFINE_CONSTANT to include/exclude piece of code is the most common reason).

You need to check the projects that are included in the solution to find the ones that uses this configuration and decide if you want to keep it for your building scenarios.

If the configuration is no more needed (Check with the uttermost attention your proejcts) you could use the Configuration Manager menu to remove it:

- Build->Configuration Manager
- Select Edit from the Active Configuration then Remove

This article on MSDN seems a good starting point to understand the need of a custom configuration [Understanding Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx)